# SwiftUI - How to add attributed accessibility label for VoiceOver, to control spoken pitch?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I want to have VoiceOver speak a `View`'s accessibility label in multiple pitches. For example, for **"Raised string. Normal string."**, I want "Raised string" to have a `1.5` pitch, and "Normal string." to have the default `1.0` pitch.

With UIKit, I can set the element's `accessibilityAttributedLabel` with a `NSAttributedString` and [`NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1620195-accessibilityspeechpitch?changes=_6). Something like this:

```
let pitchAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch: 1.5]
let string = NSMutableAttributedString()

let raisedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Raised string.", attributes: pitchAttribute)
string.append(raisedString)

let normalString = NSAttributedString(string: "Normal string.")
string.append(normalString)

squareView.isAccessibilityElement = true
squareView.accessibilityAttributedLabel = string
```

The result, which is exactly I want ([Audio link](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1_SXdpKvH8kOvMkdbMlU8xGJNLGXEZdfI)):

[image: Blue square with VoiceOver cursor on it]

However, with SwiftUI, there only seems to be a `.accessibility(label: Text)` modifier. This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .accessibility(label: Text("Raised string. Normal string."))
    }
}
```

And this is the result ([Audio link](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1ZOHsjdP-XZzpC1MDVVCjcSKEmlA_XnpQ)):

[image: Blue square with VoiceOver cursor on it]

As you can hear, "Raised string." and "Normal string." are spoken in the same pitch. This is as expected, because I passed in a solitary `Text` for the label.

But is there any way I can set the spoken pitch in SwiftUI? I can't find a way to set just one pitch, never mind two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Love to see developers working to include accessibility!

In iOS 15, you can have your function return an [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) and then set the view's accessibility label with that `AttributedString` from your function:

`.accessibility(label: Text(getAccessibilityAttributedLabel()))`

A sample function with one pitch value:

```
func getAccessibilityAttributedLabel() -> AttributedString {
    var pitchSpeech = AttributedString("Raised pitch")
    pitchSpeech.accessibilitySpeechAdjustedPitch = 1.5
    return pitchSpeech
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess it's `UIViewRepresentable` time (Yay ). Unless someone has a better answer, this is what I came up with:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RectangleView(
            accessibilityAttributedLabel: getAccessibilityAttributedLabel(), 
            fill: UIColor.blue /// pass color into initializer
        )
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    
    /// make the attributed string
    func getAccessibilityAttributedLabel() -> NSAttributedString {
        let pitchAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechPitch: 1.5]
        let string = NSMutableAttributedString()

        let raisedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Raised string.", attributes: pitchAttribute)
        string.append(raisedString)

        let normalString = NSAttributedString(string: "Normal string.")
        string.append(normalString)
        
        return string
    }
}

struct RectangleView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var accessibilityAttributedLabel: NSAttributedString
    var fill: UIColor
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIView {
        let uiView = UIView()
        uiView.backgroundColor = fill
        uiView.isAccessibilityElement = true
        uiView.accessibilityAttributedLabel = accessibilityAttributedLabel /// set the attributed label here
        
        return uiView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {}
}
```

Comment: For iOS 15 use .accessibility(label: Text(getAccessibilityAttributedLabel())) - return an AttributedString instead of NSAttributedString

Comment: @RanLearns interesting, do you know which attributes in `AttributedString` affect voiceover?

Comment: pitch, punctuation, here's the list: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/accessibilityattributes